# ASP.NET - How to postback a page after a file download?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here my situation :

The user click on a LinkButton, and the page does a PostBack. But I also need to prompt a file download to the user at the same time.

In order to do that, I did this on the LinkButton

```
lnkPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('Download.ashx?type=x')");
```

The **Download.ashx** Http Handler generates the file (Content-Type : **application/pdf**), and if I click on my LinkButton, it does PostBack and download the file after showing a popup... But I can't manage to close this popup automatically.

I tried some methods

- settimeout('self.close()',1000) after the download
- Setting a RegisterStartupScript on the LinkButton.Command, to trigger the download after the postback, but IE6 prompts a warning that disturbs my users

So, none of these methods seems to work fine.

So, my question is : Is there a way to make the popup instantly disappear, or is there a means to make the page download the file **AND** postback at the same time ?

PS : I thought of the **Your download will begin shortly** method, but I'm afraid I'll have the same issues as before with the RegisterStartupScript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to close the window immediately, do you really need the window at all?  Can't you just do:

`<a href="Download.ashx?type=x">Download</a>`

Then there is no popup, and if the content disposition is set to attachment, you won't redirect the user to a blank page.

Comment: I need to know if the user clicked on the LinkButton, so I have to get the Command event. Unfortunately, if I redirect on the download.ashx, the page won't postback.

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding - Why does the page have to postback?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a normal postback, but then make your response, the file download?  Just do Response.BinaryWrite()... and use Response.ContentType
Also, you can set the content-disposition header to the filename of your choice.

Comment: That won't work, because the download page will end the response. In other terms, I can't both have an application/pdf response and a postback response